# How to Add XLSX to server side Node JS

Tags: node.js, excel, xlsx

I want it to read *XLSX Excel* file on server side

I try to install with *"node install xlsx"*

```
var XLSX = require('xlsx');


        var XLSdata = null;
        const fs = require('fs');
        // First I want to read the file
        //console.log("ovde", fs);
        fs.readFile('/roster.xls', function (err, data) {
          ///console.log("dir", __dirname);
          console.log("error", err);
          //console.log("ovde",data);
          XLSdata = data;
        });
      try {
        var workbook = XLSX.read(XLSdata, {type: 'binary'});
      }

      catch(err) {
          console.log("error",err.message);
        return;
      }
```

When I compile code I got the **error:**

> "Error: Cannot find module 'xlsx'"

Comment: **npm** install ...

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx

Answer (score 0):

To install it:

`npm i xlsx`

To use it:

```
const XLSX = require("xlsx");

let workbook = XLSX.readFile("./test.xlsx");

console.log(workbook);
```

(You can use var here instead of const and let)

Answer (score 0):

You can use xlsx npm package for this.

npm install xlsx
https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx

Here is some example code in my case using node js:

```
const xlsxController= {};
const XLSX = require('xlsx');

xlsxController.getXlxsData= async (req, res) => {
   try {
       var workbook = XLSX.readFile('fileName.xlsx'); 
       // file should be placed in root directory of your project.
       // in my case my file is placed in public folder so I am using 'public/fileName.xlsx'
       var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;
       let data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheet_name_list[0]]);
       // sheet_name_list[0] is the number for the sheet from which you wants to read data, you can use file name instead of '0' in i.e sheet_name_list['sheetName']
       return res.status(200).send({
           message: 'Request Processed Successfully',
           data: data,
      });
   } catch (error) {
        console.log("error:", error);
        return res.status(500).send({
            message: 'Internal server error',
            error: error
        });
   }
}

module.exports = xlsxController;


// Output in my case:  
data: [    
  { clubName: 'A.l.c.g.a. ', region: 'Aberdeenshire' },  
  { clubName: 'Abbey Hill', region: 'Berks, Bucks & Oxon' },   
  { clubName: 'Abbey Hotel Golf & C.c. ', region: 'Worcestershire' },    
  { clubName: 'Abbey Moor' },   
 ]
```